# Hyphen in div id causing javascript error

Tags: javascript, forms, character

I'm having an issue with javascript whereby i am performing the following to close a popup window and update a field in the parent window with the required value. Code looks something like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var FieldID = document.form.field22-1.value;
    self.parent.opener.document.+FieldID = 'some text';
    window.top.window.close();
</script>
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Error: missing ; before statement
```

I have a funny feeling the javascript is interpreting the field id (field22-1) as having a subtraction in it. Which I guess would make sense. Any ideas/help would be ridiculously appreciated, really don't want to have to go back in and change the - in the code!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Never try to get elements directly. It just causes problems (as you can see)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById('field22-1').value` instead.

You might also need to fix this:

```
self.parent.opener.document[FieldID] = 'some text';
```

Comment: Ahh, y'know I should have realised I should have used detElementById! Guess that's what you get from all day JavaScript hell when in reality I hate the thing (to some degree)! Still getting errors but for other reasons which I think is all realted...

Comment: With some tweaking here is the result:
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   var FieldID = self.parent.opener.document.getElementById("field22-0");
    FieldID.value = 'some content';
   window.top.window.close();
  </script>

simple when you know how eh!
Ta guys!

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, any property of any object can be accessed either via dot notation, e.g. `foo.bar`, or bracket notation, e.g. `foo["bar"]`. The latter is necessary when your property is not a legal identifier (as in your case):

```
var FieldID = document.form["field22-1"].value;
```

Alternatively, if this is an actual `id` attribute, you should use:

```
var FieldID = document.getElementById('field22-1').value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `document.form['field22-1'].value`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.getElementById('field22-1').value`